# Could a faulty fuel level sensor cause a vehicle to stall?

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, stall, santa-fe

I have a 2007 Hyundai Santa Fe with just over 90,000 KMs and recently the fuel gauge started to fluctuate wildly.  I had the sensor's replaced and filled the tank and it only showed half full.  So one of the new sensors was faulty, so that was replaced and all seemed good. The vehicle worked fine during this time, but I didn't know how much fuel there was.  About a month later I was driving up a slight hill and the vehicle stalled.  The electric still worked, but the power brakes and steering didn't.  I pulled over and the tried to start it and it turned over but didn't start.  After 5 minutes I tried again and it was fine.  I didn't notice if the fuel gauge was off, but I had filled up a few days before so there was three quarters of a tank of gas.  I drove for another 30 minutes without incident.  I parked in my driveway and left the car running. When I returned 2 minutes later the car had shut down.  My wife said it went to empty and then shut off.  I tried the car a few minutes later and it showed empty but started.  Then shut off.  I tried again and it went back to normal.  Then a minute later it went to empty again and died.  Electrical was still working.  I left the car and tried again a day later and it started and seemed fine.  The check engine light was on.  I took it to the dealer and they checked the code and it said the fuel sensors were bad again so they replaced them.  They didn't thinkn the sensors would lead to the car stalling the way it did.

My wife is now afraid to drive without difinitive proof that the sensors caused the stall.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to report this to Hyundai directly. The more people that report it the sooner Hyundai will put out a "campaign" aka a recall for it. Then you will just be able to take it to the dealer and have them fix it for you. Tell everyone you know! Just spoke with Hyundai and that was their advice to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sensor should not cause the engine to stall. All of the accessories not working (power steering and brakes) would be normal with a stalled engine. What I would be looking at is the fuel pump might be going bad. A mechanic can easily check this by placing a fuel pressure sensor on the fuel line to check the pressure. If the engine is losing fuel pressure, it would stall and would show up directly on the pressure gauge. If the engine is stalling as much as you say, it shouldn't take them long to figure out if this is the issue.

Even if the fuel pump is going out, this does not equate to the issues you are seeing with your fuel gauge. The are two different things, though the sensor is co-located with the pump in the fuel tank.

Check with your Hyundai dealer. If you bought this vehicle new, I *believe* it should still be under warranty considering what you have stated with vehicle age and mileage.

I don't blame your wife for not wanting to drive the vehicle as it could surely cause her to be stranded.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paulster2

Or maybe you have two different issues:
Fuel sensors or related wiring
Something else that causes your car to die.

The car only dies when the gauge shows empty?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check both fuel pumps? Could one be working and one not.  There are two on the 2007 one under the driver’s side and one under the passenger side.

Comment: Are there really? I only find reference to one when I look this up. I think you may be confusing the secondary level sender with a pump.

Answer (score 1):

i have a 2007 hyundai accent that is having the same problem and it would stall all the time and i had to let it sit for a while before it would start. i ask around and a friend told me to check the map sensor. so i got a new one and put it in and had no more problems with the car stalling. so check that and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for an exact answer to this problem. The vehicle stalling is due to the throttle body. Get it cleaned and the stalling will stop. However the gas gauge issue you’re having is the fuel level sensor. I know this post is old but for anyone else looking to solve this problem, I just did all of this with my 08 Santa Fe. Google is the truth! Lol!